# In excel is it possible to update a single cell with the username of a person who modifies any cell on that specific row?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I am creating a target sheet for my team, where they will put in the customer name, the target, opportunities etc. across a row in an excel worksheet. They can have multiple rows with different customers, and everyone on the team will be working from the same sheet.

I want one cell in each row to add the team members name who edits any data in that row.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using VBA the specific function is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Range("A" & Target.row).value = Environ("Username")  
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need an `&` in there: `Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Environ("Username")`

Comment: Agreed modified to include the ampersand

Comment: That does not seem to be working - It makes no difference at all. Do I have to call that function from the sheet itself? Apologies, if this is basic.

Comment: Yes it has to be within the same sheet

Comment: The function above results in a Run-time error '28': Out of stack space. Any idea why/how to resolve?